# No records found for Index Management

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, indexing

I'm working on a Magento site and there are 'No records found' on the Index Management admin panel.

[image]

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I believe there is no products or any other attributes to refresh the index for. Just guess.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can rename the app/etc/local.xml and its ask to reinstall the magento, so process the installation steps and add the same database name, so in case database is corrupt then it will resolve the issue.